# sqldf R Error create a table

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I am doing some experiments with SQL in **R** using the sqldf package.
I am trying to test some commands to check the output, in particular I am trying to create tables.

Here the code:

```
sqldf("CREATE TABLE tbl1 AS
       SELECT cut
       FROM diamonds")
```

Very simple code, however I get this error

```
sqldf("CREATE TABLE tbl1 AS
+ SELECT cut
+       FROM diamonds")
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
Warning message:
In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries
```

Why is it saying the the table create as 0 columns and 0 rows?
Can someone help?

Comment: try `tbl1 <- sqldf("select cut from diamonds")`

Comment: Thanks Mike, like that it works perfectly, I wanted to understand why the CREATE TABLE instruction does not.

Comment: I thought CREATE TABLE was something from SQL itself https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Comment: Yes, `create table` is a standard SQL statement.

Comment: Interesting I never used that in SQL before, not sure why it wouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a warning, not an error.  The warning is caused by a backward incompatibility in recent versions of RSQLite. You can ignore it since it works anyways.

The sqldf statement that is shown in the question

- creates an empty database
- uploads the `diamonds` data frame to a table of the same name in that database
- runs the `create` statement which creates a second table `tbl1` in the database
- returns nothing (actually a 0 column 0 row data frame) since a `create` statement has no value
- destroys the database

When using `sqldf` you don't need `create` statements. It automatically creates a table in the backend database for any data frame referenced in your sql statement so the following `sqldf` statement

```
sqldf("select * from diamonds")
```

will

- create an empty database
- upload `diamonds` to it
- run the `select` statement
- return the result of the `select` statement as a data frame
- destroy the database

You can use the `verbose=TRUE` argument to see the individual calls to the lower level RSQLite (or other backend database if you specify a different backend):

```
sqldf("select * from diamonds limit 3", verbose = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
sqldf: library(RSQLite)
sqldf: m <- dbDriver("SQLite")
sqldf: connection <- dbConnect(m, dbname = ":memory:")
sqldf: initExtension(connection)
sqldf: dbWriteTable(connection, 'diamonds', diamonds, row.names = FALSE)
sqldf: dbGetQuery(connection, 'select * from diamonds limit 3')
sqldf: dbDisconnect(connection)
  carat     cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1  0.23   Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
2  0.21 Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
3  0.23    Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
```

Suggest you thoroughly review `help("sqldf")` as well as the info on the [sqldf github home page](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. one thing, why do you say that returns nothing since a create statement has no value? and how can I create the desired output using CREATE?

Comment: `sqldf(c("create table X as ...", "select * from X"))` will return `X`.  Please read the documentation cited at the end of my answer.  It's all discussed.  It may be that you want to use the lower level RSQLite package directly rather than the higher level sqldf.